# Change font locally (fdd)

Tags: fonts

I just started writing in latex, and am very disapponted about how to change the font for one sentence/paragraph. I read multiple questions but there is no real explanation.
What I was trying to achieve was to write the first page of my document in Bembo Std, but it seems that fonts have to be relased in packages, I cannot simply use one which is located in my machine. So, I searched for an alternative, and found the package `fdd`, but I have not been able to find how to use this only for one page and not for the whole document.
This is one of the ways I tried:

```
\documentclass [11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fbb}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\graphicspath{ {./Images/} }

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\includegraphics[width=8.13cm,height=2.78cm,keepaspectratio]{Logo}\\
\bigskip

{\fontfamily{fbb}\selectfont 
Text in fbb
}

\fontsize{16}{12}\selectfont {\bf Text}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,right=0.5in,left=1.5in}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: you can use fonts directly if you use lualatex or xelatex. pdflatex is a bit more complicated as it needs a number of supporting files. But you don't need a package here, only the correct family name `{\fontfamily{fbb-TLF}\selectfont Text in fbb}` should work.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer. Does this mean I could also use `Bembo Std` (supposing I have it installed on my pc) by using lualatex?

Comment: yes, see the documentation of fontspec.

Comment: as a new user I'm surprised to see you using `\bf` (which has not been defined by default since 1993 and is just defined in the book class for compatibility with systems that are oder than that). In particular `\bf` (unlike standard latex commands) does _not_ select the bold version of the current font, it always selects the same font, the bold version of the document default font.  use the standard `\bfseries word` or `\textbf{word}`  to get the bold version of the current font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for the suggestion! I really just started and all I am doing is some copy/pasting from forums for now.

Comment: you are copying some very suspect code (that `\\ ` must be warning you about badness 10000 as well (you should delete it) and seeing `\bf`  this century is rather weird.

Comment: I could suggest https://www.learnlatex.org/  as a more reliable source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using system fonts it is best to use lualatex (or xelatex) rather than pdflatex.

I don't have the font but here I show using one paragraph set in Arial system font from Windows, you could use Bembo Std if it is installed in your system just by changing the font name where indicated.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\bembo{Arial}% Bembo Std

\begin{document}

{\bembo

a paragraph (not) in bembo std

}

a paragraph in Latin Modern

\end{document}
```